# Cardview doesn't appear like in layout when i run it in my device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gridview, android-cardview

I'm using CardView to Display my Image view in Scrollable GridLayout. But It appears fine when I go to Design Tab but when I run on Device it appears Different.

On Layout It appears as
[image]

and when I run on Device it appears as
[image]

My build.gradle ( app ) contains

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nepalpolice.androidgridlayout"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and my layout contains

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textGrid"
                android:text="GRID LAYOUT"
                android:textSize="34sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="14dp"
            >

            <!-- Row 1 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/me_time"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Me"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/family_time"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Family"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/lovely_time"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Lovely"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/team_time"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Team"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/friends"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Friends"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Calendars"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and my Mainactivity file contains

```js
package com.nepalpolice.androidgridlayout;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridLayout mainGrid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);


    }
}
```

I also search for solution but found nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think u can add design support library `compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'`

Comment: @MohammadAli should I add the line inside build gradle dependencies?

Comment: wait wait u can change your gradle file before put your answer ?

Comment: @MohammadAli I added this line compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+' on my gradle file but it is same.

Comment: ok but it's necessary to applied library becoz for additional design :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using older version of **GridLayout** use from support library it's backward compatible and supports weights.

So you just need to add `compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'` to your build.gradle

And in xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="14dp"
        >
```

Don't forget to **import** correct class **android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout** in FullscreenActivity instead of **android.widget.GridLayout**.

Comment: It appears great but my background image is not visible and also when I scroll then button overlaps and it looks total messy. How can i fix it ..here is the image https://ibb.co/hBsWrS

Comment: Yes it's totally messy I suggest you to redesign whole layout again using android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout there many view properties which overlapping each other.

Comment: I viewed the tutorial from youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUPM387qyrw&t=29s and did the whole thing...I have no idea to build a whole layout over again....any idea how can I do this or could you please post the redesigned layout from the refrence above as it'd be helpful for future refrence also for Others.